# Extract image from HTML/JS canvas with Python (convert)

Tags: javascript, python, canvas

I am making a discord bot with Python for a game community I am in, and right now I am making a command that returns the status of the games (using [this](https://downdetector.com/status/world-of-tanks/) website). Full code for that command is [here](https://mystb.in/UnusualTraditionalMidnight.python).

Now that shows only this:

[image]

However I want to add the graph that you can find on [the website](https://downdetector.com/status/world-of-tanks/) as well, I use BeautifulSoup to get the other values, and getting an image would also be easy. **However the graph is not an image**, it is a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) object used in JavaScript/HTML. I don't know how the math works, but I can 'convert' it to an image locally very easily by just right clicking, and then copying the image.

My question is: **How can I retrieve this canvas object as an image in my Python code?**

When I google this question I mostly get results for Tkinter, and nothing helpful really.

- [How I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K77Ox.jpg)
- [Website code for the graph](https://hastebin.com/noseqageci.html)
- [What the graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKVky.jpg)

Comment: I think you can execute JavaScript code in the python code if you are web scraping the website. The js canvas has the ability to convert the canvas into a base64 image string, so you can execute the following JS code in your python `document.getElementById("holder").toDataURL()` this will return a base64 PNG string which you can convert into an image and output through your discord bot.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want this. Since the plot data is pre-injected into html from server side only way to get the data is to parse the script and grab the values into Python data type (preferably Pandas dataframe, so that its easier to plot).

I have written the following messy code that may help you. I have used [PyJSParser](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/pyjsparser) to parse the script. And grab the variable's value from it.

I have left some comments inside the code. Please read.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from pyjsparser import parse
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def parseScript(scriptContent):
    res = parse(scriptContent)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'report'])

    # This part is very tricky
    # Since the parsing tree is multiple layer deep 
    # And there is no guarantee that the server won't change the order we have 
    # to consider traversing all of it to make sure if it is infact what we want. 
    # comment out the print statements to see what I mean by multi level deep.
    # its a rabbit hole. 

    for obj in res['body']:
        if obj['type'] == 'VariableDeclaration':
            for declaration in obj['declarations']:
                if declaration['type'] == 'VariableDeclarator':
                    if declaration['id']['name'] == 'data':
                        # print(declaration.keys())
                        # print(declaration['type'])
                        # print(declaration['id'])
                        # print(declaration['init'].keys())
                        # print(declaration['init']['type'])
                        # print(type(declaration['init']['properties']))
                        for subVar in declaration['init']['properties']:
                            # print(subVar.keys())
                            # print(subVar['type'])
                            # print(subVar['key'])
                            if subVar['key']['name'] == 'series':
                                # print(len(subVar['value']))
                                # print(type(subVar['value']))
                                # print(subVar['value'].keys())
                                # print(len(subVar['value']['elements']))

                                for element in subVar['value']['elements']:
                                    # print(type(element))
                                    # print(element.keys())
                                    # print(element['properties'][0].keys())
                                    timestamp = element['properties'][0]['value']['value']
                                    report = element['properties'][1]['value']['value']
                                    df.loc[len(df)] = [timestamp, report]
    return df

def scraper(soup):
    # first we must filter the div in which the chart's script reside
    # so we don't mistakenly take any other script from the page
    chartDiv = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'chart-row'})
    print(len(chartDiv))
    
    scriptContent = chartDiv[0].find_all('script')[0].string

    reportData = parseScript(scriptContent)
    return reportData

def plotData(df, duration=24):
    '''
    @param df dataframe gotten from scraped web pages script
    @param duration duration in HOUR of which data to plot
    '''
    import datetime as dt
    import pytz
    # pre process a bit
    # convert timestamp frame into datetime object
    df['timstamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

    # the timezone is fixed from the source
    timeZone = pytz.FixedOffset(-240)
    df = df[df['timstamp'] >= (dt.datetime.now(timeZone) - dt.timedelta(hours=duration))]

    times = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
    df = df.groupby([times.dt.hour])['report'].sum()
    
    df.plot(x = 'timestamp', y = 'report')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('lala.html', 'rb') as file:
        soup = bs(file, 'html5lib')

    data = scraper(soup)
    plotData(data)
```

Install the following libraries

- html5lib (for better html parsing)
- pandas
- matplotlib
- pyjsparser

Now for the graph part, I think the beautification is up to you. From the method `scraper()` you get the dataframe you can use to plot your graph.

I have plotted the graph very simply which may or may not be of your liking. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! Sorry I didn’t catch it earlier, I will work on it tomorrow and try out your code :)